# Change the order of integrals..

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration

$$\int_0^1dx\int_0^{1-x}dy\int_0^{x+y}f(x,y,z)dz$$

to$$\int dz\int dx \int f(x,y,z) dy$$

Not sure if to split the shape into two shapes, or do it directly. Either way i would like to know how its done..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From this formulation of the integral
$$I=\int_0^1\left[\int_0^{1-x}\left(\int_0^{x+y}f(x,y,z)\ \ dz\right)dy\right]dx$$
one can infer that the region of integration is like as shown below.
[image]

In the requested formulation, one has to integrate first with respect to $y$ when $x$ and $z$ are given. The integration with respect to $y$ depends on the relationship of $x$ and $z$. If $0<x<z$ then $z-x<y<1-x$ , however, if $z<x<1$
then $0<y<1-x$. So,
$$I=\int_0^1\left[\int_0^z\left(\int_{z-x}^{1-x}f(x,y,z)\ \ dy\right)dx+\int_{z}^{1}\left(\int_{0}^{1-x}f(x,y,z)\ \ dy\right)dx\right]dz.$$

Comment: how did you conclude : If 0<x<z then z−x<y<1−x , however, if z<x<1 then 0<y<1−x.

Comment: Take a pair of (x,z) and shoot at the volume perpendicular to the xz plane. If x>z then you hit the xz wall and will integrate from 0 to 1-x (by y). If x<z then your bullet hits the roof...